# Is LINQ to SQL InsertOnSubmit() subject to SQL Injection Attack?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, sql-injection

I have code like this:

```
var newMsg = new Msg
{
    Var1 = var1,
    Var2 = var2
};

using (AppDataContext appDataContext = new AppDataContext(ConnectionString))
{
    appDataContext.CClass.InsertOnSubmit(newMsg);
    appDataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157924/does-linqs-executecommand-provide-protection-from-sql-injection-attacks) I believe that the same logic applies.

Does anyone think that this is subject to SQL Injection Attack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second answer in the post you're referencing says it:

> LINQ to SQL uses *execute_sql* with
>   parameters.

It does not concatenate property values into a one big INSERT ... VALUES('...', '...')

Comment: I'm not sure that it does... it is just a command that is parameterised. execute_sql is used to do the same from *within* TSQL.

Comment: User input that is parameterised is safe from injection. Injection attacks only apply when user input is concatenated.

Answer (score 3):

The underlying operation of the DataContext is via the SqlCommand which uses paramatised SQL.

So your insert statement will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO [MSG] [Var1] = @p1, [Var2] = @p2
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but you should be validating user data anyhow.